# unicode error when reading fastq files - python 3.4.2

Tags: python, unicode, fastq

I am trying to read fastq files but I keep getting the following error:

(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 18 -19: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

I used the following code:

```
file = open(r'C:\Users\jim\Documents\samples\3009_TGACCA_L005_R1_trimmed.fq\3009_TGACCA_L005_R1_trimmed.fq','r', newline = '' )

for i, line in file:
    if i < 5:
        print (line)

file.close()
```

Could I please get some advice on how I might be able to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to duplicate all backslashes `\ => \\` without the `r'` prefix